# Keeping Local User Account Clean?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, default-settings

I work for a training firm that has a set of computers that are available for people that are taking courses at our company. All of the machines are running Windows 7 and are not connected to a domain.

### Question

Is it possible to reset local user account profile settings, and ensure any saved files get wiped upon logoff of the local user accounts? I'd like to make sure that what the user did on the account gets reset, and any locally saved files get deleted per each logon and/or logoff?

Comment: If you are not looking for a software solution, I encourage you to edit your question, to make that clear.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a configuration of **Windows 7** then you can look at [Creating a Mandatory User Profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241183(WS.10).aspx?tduid=(a9a1a740bde8a61c80c4b72c3e30b229)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-wmN0fWlerK091Y5eSWb0Nw)()). If you're software shopping, then you may want to check out [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

> ### [Mandatory User Profiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> A mandatory user profile is a special type of pre-configured roaming
>   user profile that administrators can use to specify settings for
>   users. With mandatory user profiles, a user can modify his or her
>   desktop, but the changes are not saved when the user logs off. The
>   next time the user logs on, the mandatory user profile created by the
>   administrator is downloaded. There are two types of mandatory
>   profiles: normal mandatory profiles and super-mandatory profiles.
>
> <sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776895(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>

---

> ### [Creating a Mandatory User Profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241183(WS.10).aspx?tduid=(a9a1a740bde8a61c80c4b72c3e30b229)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-wmN0fWlerK091Y5eSWb0Nw)())
>
> > <sub>Applies To: Windows 7</sub>
>
> The first step to creating a mandatory user profile is to create a
>   default user profile. The section titled [Configuring Standard User
>   Accounts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241188(v=ws.10).aspx), describes how to create a default user profile. You must
>   create a folder for the mandatory user profile and configure its
>   permissions so that everyone can access it. Then you copy the default
>   user profile to the mandatory user profile folder.
>
> Windows 7 recognizes a mandatory user profile that is based on the
>   name of the registry hive file. Each user profile contains a registry
>   hive file named Ntuser.dat, which contains the user’s registry
>   settings. Renaming it to Ntuser.man causes Windows 7 to make the user
>   profile mandatory.
>
> **To create a mandatory user profile**
>
> 1. Copy the default user profile that you created in [Configuring
>      Standard User Accounts](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241188(v=ws.10).aspx) to C:\Users on the shared computer.
> 2. Rename the folder Mandatory.v2. (The root part of the file name can
>      be anything you like, but the folder name must end with “.v2” to
>      identify it as a Windows 7 user profile folder.)
> 3. Use the following procedure to rename Ntuser.dat to Ntuser.man:
>
>    a. Open C:\Users\Mandatory.v2 in Windows Explorer.
>
>    b. In Windows Explorer, click **Organize**, and then click F**older and search options**.
>
>    c. On the **View** tab, select the **Show hidden files and folders** check box, clear the **Hide protected operating system files** check box, click
>      **Yes** to confirm that you want to show operating system files, and then
>      click **OK** to save your changes.
>
>    d. Rename Ntuser.dat to Ntuser.man. Figure 3 shows what this should look like in Windows Explorer with hidden files showing.
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>[source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg241183(WS.10).aspx?tduid=(a9a1a740bde8a61c80c4b72c3e30b229)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-wmN0fWlerK091Y5eSWb0Nw)())</sub>

Comment: Thanks! That sound exactly what we need. I'll check it out next week! Also thanks for the software recommendations link, I save that for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill, but the most common product I've heard of for resetting computers is Faronics Deep Freeze, http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/.